# Column navigation

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

Is there any module available for column navigation style for eg. [joomla main navigation](http://www.joomla.org/)? . I am using joomla 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I think they might be using [IceMegaMenu](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/drop-a-tab-menus/16468), which I've tried myself and works really well. I personally think that it should be integreted as a standar feature, as it really chenges the way menus act and is 100% compatible (you may even choose to make it work without js, and results are still great).

PS Hoping that this won't be considered spam, you can see the menu in action, as I've implemented it, at [my web site](http://www.beachpartyfever.com). It's a very standard version, without js.
For a complete overveiw of the features you may have a look at the [official Demo](http://demo.icetheme.com/extensions16/icemegamenu), it really looks like Joomla.org relies on IceMegaMenu...